# ContentfulReact .env.environment file error

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, contentful, react-snap

I created a blog with contentful api in the client folder with the api keys located in the .env.devlopment file. I also have an .env file to hold my api keys for cloudinary in the same client folder. I can see all of my content and upload audio when I tested out my react site but i have problem when running **`npm run build`** in the terminal. I have no errors in the localhost but I receive an error of `Expected parameter accessToken` when I prepare to deploy to heroku. i removed `ReactDOM` from ReactDOM.render in my index.js file and i get a question about replacing the call to ReactDOM.render.

contentful.js file:

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful';

export default createClient({
  space: process.env.REACT_APP_API_SPACE,
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
});

.env.enviroment file:

 REACT_APP_API_SPACE= my access key
 REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN= my access token
```

Error in terminal when i run `npm run build`

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken]
Object.t.createClient 
'render' from react-snapshot was never called. Did you replace the call to ReactDOM.render()?
```

When I run console.log(process.env); I receive

```
console.log(process.env);
1.  {NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "", WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}
1.  FAST_REFRESH: true
2.  NODE_ENV: "development"
3.  PUBLIC_URL: ""
4.  REACT_APP_API: "http://localhost:8000/api"
5.  REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME: "********"
6.  REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_SECRET: "*******"
7.  REACT_APP_SPACE_ID: "*********"
8.  REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN: "***********"
```

client.env

```
REACT_APP_API: "http://localhost:8000/api"
    REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME: "********"
    REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_SECRET: "*******"
```

client.env.development

```
REACT_APP_SPACE_ID: "*********"
 REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN: "***********"
```

Comment: Did you define the environment variables on heroku? `.env` files usually don't make it to remote environments because they're included in the `.gitignore` configuration.

Comment: yes I defined the environment variables set in heroku Config Vars section  and I have both .env and .env.development files in git ignore not sure if I should have 2 .env files because contentful document suggest to create an .env.devlopment file. I added console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID); and i receive an undefined in the console.